# What stops exchanges and other whales with large amounts of EOS voting on referendum proposals and skewing the outcome?

Tags: voting, exchange

Exchanges and whales have large amounts of EOS. They can easily vote on referendum proposals and skew the outcome. What prevents these large holders from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently nothing in place to limit/cap voting on referendum proposals.

Answer (score 2):

EOS is a plutocracy. The idea is that the large token holders have the most to gain or lose from system-wide changes, so their interests should align with the interests of the network as a whole.